# .NET equivalent of Java's TreeSet operations tailSet and headSet?

Tags: java, .net, collections

I'm trying to use .NET 4's `SortedSet<T>` collection.  It seems to have everything I need minus a couple things.

**Q**: I want to be able to fetch all elements lower or higher in comparison to a given value.  In Java's `TreeSet`, there are methods named `tailSet` and `headSet`, which perform these operations.  I'd like to be able to do the same with `SortedSet<T>`.  The closest I can find is `GetViewBetween`.  However, what if I wanted to use SortedSet with `string`?  There is no max value of `string` that I know of, yet I need to give the method an upper and lower bounds.

How could I mimic the behavior of `tailSet` and `headSet` using `SortedSet`?  Considering the implementation of `SortedSet`, I'd think that these would be very easy methods to implement.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can emulate them like this:
`sortedSet.GetViewBetween(start, sortedSet.Max)`
`sortedSet.GetViewBetween(sortedSet.Min, end)`

```
static SortedSet<T> TailSet<T>(this SortedSet<T> set, T start)
{
    return set.GetViewBetween(start, set.Max);
}

static SortedSet<T> HeadSet<T>(this SortedSet<T> set, T end)
{
    return set.GetViewBetween(set.Min, end);
}
```

Alternately, you can use LINQ:

```
static SortedSet<T> TailSet<T>(this SortedSet<T> set, T start)
{
    return new SortedSet<T>(set.SkipWhile(
        x => set.Comparer.Compare(x, start) < 0));
}

static SortedSet<T> HeadSet<T>(this SortedSet<T> set, T end)
{
    return new SortedSet<T>(set.TakeWhile(
        x => set.Comparer.Compare(x, end) < 0));
}
```

The primary difference is that `GetViewBetween` gives you an object with a pointer to the original set, so any changes in the original set can be reflected in the copies. The LINQ version creates a new set based on the contents of the original, giving copies that don't track each other. Of course, you could also do something like `new SortedSet<T>(set.GetViewBetween(set.Min, end))` to get the cloning behavior.

Comment: For the LINQ approach, you should use the `SortedSet`'s `Comparer` instead of the default.  Just in case the set has a custom comparer.

Comment: Jeff: Good point. I didn't realize that `Comparer` was a public property.

Comment: Would the Linq versions iterate over every item in the sorted set while GetViewBetween would use the internal tree structure to fetch the range?  I ask because it looks like GetViewBetween would be a O(log n) operation while the Linq equivalent would be O(n)

Comment: Polaris878: You are correct in theory, but I think that GetViewBetween counts the nodes in the set, so it too is O(n).

Answer (score 1):

I think a little LINQ may solve the problem:

```
        var sortedSet = new SortedSet<string>();
        sortedSet.Add("Santiago");
        sortedSet.Add("Alejandra");
        sortedSet.Add("Carolina");
        sortedSet.Add("Sebastián");

        var head = sortedSet.Where(s => string.Compare(s, "Carolina") < 0);
        var tail = sortedSet.Where(s => string.Compare(s, "Carolina") >= 0);
```